# How to assign a value to a alias in a loop

Tags: python, list, alias

If the variable is a list, I want to assign the first element in that list to the variable's alias.  The following does NOT work.

```
a = 1
b = [2]
L = [a,b]
for x in L:
    if isinstance(x,list):
        x = x[0]
print(b)
```

When I run this, I still get a list.  The desired output is:

```
2
```

Comment: do you mean to assign the result back to b instead of x? `b = x[0]`

Comment: Yes.  Assume that I have a long list.

Comment: What is there to assume? It appears that your code has a typo, you never change the value of `b` but are expecting it to have changed

Comment: with this line `L = [a,b]`, `L` and `b` point to different objects and changing `L` will not result in changing `b` if that's what you are expecting.

Comment: Instead of them being their own variables, could you have a and b as keys in a dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, Rolv.

```
d = {'a':1,'b':[2]}
for x,y in zip(d,d.values()):
    if isinstance(y,list):
        d[x] = y[0]
print(d['b'])
```